# Change background color of header on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, scroll

I want to change the background color of my header (from transparent to black) when it scrolls. How can I do this?

I use a CMS to create the header. That is my code at the moment:

```html
<script>
  jQuery(function($) {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      if ($(document).scrollTop() > 50) {
        $('#section-padding').addClass('reduce-section-padding');
        $('#row-width').addClass('increase-row-width');
        $('#my-site-logo').addClass('reduce-logo');
      } else {
        $('#section-padding').removeClass('reduce-section-padding');
        $('#section-padding').addClass('slow-transition');
        $('#row-width').removeClass('increase-row-width');
        $('#row-width').addClass('slow-transition');
        $('#my-site-logo').removeClass('reduce-logo');
        $('#my-site-logo').addClass('slow-transition');
      }
    });
  });
</script>

<style>
  .reduce-section-padding {
    transition: all 0.9s ease-out 0s;
    padding-top: 0px !important;
    padding-bottom: 0px !important;
  }
  
  .reduce-logo {
    transition: all 0.9s ease-out 0s;
    transform: scale(0.8) !important;
    /* Standard syntax */
    /*content: url(/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/favicon.png) !important;*/
  }
  
  .increase-row-width {
    transition: all 0.9s ease-out 0s;
    width: 70% !important;
  }
  
  .slow-transition {
    transition: all 0.9s ease-out 0s;
  }
  
  #main-content {
    margin-top: 5vw;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Can you add your html and css and create a snippet?

Comment: This is the web site, and here you can see the header
https://www.carpacomunication.it/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use plain JavaScript like this:
(JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/omartheman949/5jLngzkh/12/)
Place the following `script` tag and it's contents under your existing `script` tag (or place the contents of the following `script` tag inside your existing `script` tag):

```
<script>
  var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
  window.onscroll = function() {
    var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
    if (window.pageYOffset === 0) {
      document.getElementById("header").style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
      document.getElementById("header").style.color = "black";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("header").style.backgroundColor = "black";
      document.getElementById("header").style.color = "white";
    }
    prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your replay, but I don't know where I have to insert this code. Cold you help me again? :D

Comment: Hey @Billy, I believe you can insert this code inside a ```<script></script>``` tag, I would think anywhere on the page. The same as your jQuery code above. I used this code in my Wordpress footer, and Wordpress replicates the footer on every page, so the code got applied to every page. So I think in a ```script``` tag right beside your jQuery script, or even sharing the same ```script``` tag as the jQuery code.

Comment: Thank you, I inserted an other section for the code and now it works! :)